# Emails from variable not working

Tags: php

I am trying to send emails but when it comes in my inbox the from email which I have mentioned is not showing up though it coming from the mail server. Why is this happening so?

```
//This one is working fine 
if($email) {
        $from     = "EditMate@editmate.co";
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:" . $from;

        echo mail($email, $subject, $message_admin, $headers);
    }

    //In this one it is not showing the from email 
    if($receipt) {
        $from     = "newproject@editmate.co";
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:" . $from;

        echo mail($receipt, $subject, $message_admin, $headers);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding from address in the $additional_parameters section of your mail() function like:

```
mail($receipt, $subject, $message_admin, $headers,"-f newproject@editmate.co");
```

Comment: Thanks A lot worked for me now but 1 more question can i write the name and email as well like we do New Project <newproject@xyz.com> is it possible to do so?